# Use Attribute In Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, aop

I have something issue on how to use Attribute in asp.net page class.
The below code slice is the background:

A method is declared like below in a aspx class page:

```
[SomeAttribute(Name=”Test”,TargetType=typeof(System.Int32)]
Public void Verify(object obj)

{

  //code to verify…

}
```

And other pages would use the attribute too.

Now I want a Module to do is that it will invoke a method before the Verify method is calling.
Currently, my solution is using a customer IHttpModule implement class to do it by registering the BeginRequest event.

In the method referred to the event, how can I get the method that is calling currently by request in asp.net ? This is the way I could know the request is calling Verify method so that I can do something with the Attribute on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out PostSharp:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

It's got all that goodness, and more, built in.

Comment: Can it be used in Asp.net (not Asp.Net Mvc)??

Comment: As far as I know, yeah. It came out way before MVC was around.